# UWP VS 2015 Scrollable Content in preview

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I designed a loooong page with a scrollable content. This works so far when I run or publish the app.
But the designer view only shows the viewable content without scrollbars to scroll in the preview (in Visual Studio).
For me as a newbie in UWP programming it would be very helpful to see the effect of any code change in the preview.
I could define a device for the preview with a resolution of 1920x20000 or so. That might work, but it there a better way?

Comment: What's the code you are using for scrolling?

Comment: Hm, I think my bad english skills made me misunderstandable. Forget about the scrolling "code". Image an App using 200 Buttons vertically arranged in a ScrollViewer (and a StackPanel). Then, running your App, you cann scroll on the tablet through the buttons. THIS is what I want to do in VS 2015s IDE in it's preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot scroll contents inside a ScrollViewer (for example, a long list of times) inside the XAML designer in VS. You can, however, use the design time height and width settings to resize the design surface to see all of the items in your long list (set d:DesignHeight="1000" and d:DesignWidth="1000" if you wanted to see 1000x1000 content in the designer).

Comment: Thank you. That is what I expected :(